# SwiperJS Swiper is not centered, whatsoever

Tags: html, css, swiper.js

I am making a Swiper in SwiperJS, and no matter how I adjust the styling, it just stays stuck to the left.
I am using Boostrap btw.
ScreenShot Below:
[Each Pixel art image is a slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F5it.png)
Code Here
**Html:**

```
<div class="row text-center">
            <div class="swiper-container swiper2">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="skillcard">
                      <img class="skillcardimg" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/123df645-7c49-4cd3-b292-825ade4e767b/skill1.png?v=1688747054870">
                      <div class="skillcardbody">
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="skillcard">
                      <img class="skillcardimg" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/123df645-7c49-4cd3-b292-825ade4e767b/skill1.png?v=1688747054870">
                      <div class="skillcardbody">
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  (More slides here, but i can cant show them, cause Stack thinks its spam)
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

**Css:**

```
.swiper2{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.skillcard{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.skillcardbody{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".swiper2", {
      
      spaceBetween: 100,
      loop: true,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 2000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
    });
```

I have messed around with some width settings, as well as centering text and items of these containers, but it stays the same - stuck to the left side of the screen.

Comment: Consider checking the Swiper CSS has been loaded on to the page, and that there are no errors in the browser devtools console relating to the Swiper initialization.